# How to use LoggingExtras DatetimeRotatingFileLogger in UTC date

Tags: logging, julia

I want to use the DatetimeRotatingFileLogger in YYYY-MM-DD format but have the datetime input in UTC instead of local computer time.

Is this a bad idea or is there a way?

https://github.com/JuliaLogging/LoggingExtras.jl#datetimerotatingfilelogger-sink